# C++ HTTP GET using socket

Tags: c++, linux, httpwebrequest, http-get

I connected to the server with the following code

```
 web_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
 inet_pton(AF_inet, "166.111.1.1", &server_address.sin_addr);
 server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
 server_address.sin_port = htons(8080);
 indicator = connect(web_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
```

The execution of the above code results in indicator being 0, which means connection to the server is successful, but when I tried to write

```
 string request = "GET http://166.111.1.1:8080/sensor?value=10.3";
 indicator = write(web_socket, request.c_str(), request.length());
```

I cannot see anything under

```
 http://166.111.1.1:8080/sensor?value=10.3
```

or

```
 http://166.111.1.1:8080/sensor
```

though the indicator equals to the request length.

Is there anything wrong with the code above? I am testing on Ubuntu 12.04 using QT Creator, GCC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP request (and reply) headers are terminated with the sequence `\r\n\r\n`; individual lines within the header are separated with a single `\r\n`.  So what you need is:

```
string request("GET http://166.111.1.1:8080/sensor?value=10.3\r\n\r\n");
```

You don't actually need the protocol and IP address in there -- you're already connected -- so this can be reduced to:

```
string request("GET /sensor?value=10.3\r\n\r\n");
```

The short version is in fact better (and more normative), because it risks fewer complications with the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use boost asio like below:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream  stream;

stream.connect(166.111.1.1, 8080);

stream << "GET /sensor?value=10.3 HTTP/1.1\r\n";
stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
stream << "Connection: close\r\n";
stream << "\r\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I avoid using boost because my code need to be transferred here and there so it is inconvenient for me to use external libraries. Actually I just found the solution as referred by goldilocks.